# Adding Element in middle of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

How to add an element at middle of an array? I have tried searching on google but **cannot find a way to do this without looping**. Can anybody help me by providing a code snippet but please don't suggest using loop as the array is heavy and performance is the bottle neck here.

**EDIT**

actually i want that every odd index element gets copied to the even index.

Example

```
myarray[0] = "a";
myarray[1] = "b";
myarray[2] = "c";
```

Answer expected

```
myarray[0] = "a";
myarray[1] = "a";
myarray[2] = "b";
myarray[3] = "b";
myarray[4] = "c";
myarray[5] = "c";
```

Comment: Array is not the right data type for quick inserting.

Comment: but do you know a way to insert element in the middle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900079/moving-element-in-array-with-c-sharp

Comment: [List insert c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've given an answer which covers a few possibilities, but if you could provide more information about what you're trying to do, the kind of data you're dealing with, and the *amount* of data you're dealing with, we're more likely to be able to give you specific advice.

Comment: Well that's clearly creating a *new* array with twice as many elements. That's easy to do, but definitely has to use a loop. You wouldn't be *inserting* anything though...

Comment: there should be a way to do this without loop as my performance will go down to "mariana trench"

Comment: No, there isn't. It's *going* to be at least linear in the number of items in the result. There's no way round that - unless you create a collection which actually only proxies requests for items to an original list. I strongly suspect your example isn't representative of your real needs though, which means it's still hard to help you.

Comment: sir the values are not real but the situation is real

Comment: You can use a list for this, but on array it is not possible. As long as you´re using an array you have to use a loop (or LINQ, which however does this internally)

Comment: ok, i can handle it with list but how to do it so that performance doesn't go down.

Comment: Go down from what? Again, we need more context. If creating a collection with all the required values in is too expensive, you need a completely different approach - and we're not going to be able to help you with that without more context.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to add an element at middle of an array?

You can't add an element *anywhere* in an array. Once an array has been created, its size is fixed - you can modify elements, but you can't add or delete them.

You could use a `List<T>` instead, which *does* allow for insertion - but which will need to copy the elements that occur after the insertion point.

You could potentially use a `LinkedList<T>` instead, but then you'd need to loop in order to *get* to the right node.

You might want to consider using some kind of tree structure instead, which may make it easier to find the right spot and then insert the data.

Alternatively, consider a redesign - we don't have much context, but you might want to consider something like collecting all the data to start with, ignoring ordering, and then sorting it into the right order.

EDIT: For your example, I wouldn't use any sort of insertion - I'd create a new list from the old one, for example:

```
// Or use Enumerable.Repeat instead of creating an array for each element.
var newList = oldList.SelectMany(x => new[] { x, x }).ToList();
```

Or do it without LINQ:

```
var copies = 2; // Or whatever
var newList = new List<string>(oldList.Count * copies);
foreach (var item in oldList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++)
    {
        newList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Fundamentally you're not going to make this any cheaper than O(N) where N is the number of items in the resulting list...

Comment: please see my extension of the question

Comment: your answer with lambda is correct but cant use it as it blocks coding at debugging time, can you suggest another way than that

Comment: @newbee: I have no idea what you mean by "blocks coding at debugging time". You'll need to be a *lot* more specific than that. If you mean you can't use Edit and Continue, I'd suggest getting out of the habit of writing significant amounts of code during debugging. Prefer unit tests which are easy to rerun after making changes.

Comment: if you use a lambda expression on .net framework platform it blocks  changes at debugging (which is my usual habbit)

Comment: @newbee: Then get out of that habit. It's not a productive one - this being just one example. If you change your code while you're debugging, how can you have any confidence that your changes wouldn't have affected the code that's already been run? Unit testing is a *much* better approach for almost all scenarios, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by using "Buffer.BlockCopy" but you have to create a seperate copy of array for it

Comment: please see my extension of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can not add element in Array. But if you are using List then method looks like:

```
public void Operation(List<string> list)
{
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0) return;

    int count = list.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            list.Insert(i + 1, list[i]);
}
```

Comment: without loop is it possible with list because my performance has gone down because of loop

Comment: @newbee You can optimize loot but it has to done with loop only. I don't find such linq extension which does this. Check with `Zip` extension that would help you to find it.

Comment: You've a false optimisation in pre-fetching `list.Count`, as it means e.g. `{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}` will become `{"1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6"}` with the last two not being doubled. You need to change `i <= count` to `i != list.Count` or `i < list.Count`.

Comment: @Jon Hanna Thanks for suggestion but my answer just a logic for question.. I think <= and != both condition are same.. In both condition 'i' wont get value greater than count of list

Comment: `<=` and `!=` are not both the same, you can use `<` or `!=` as you prefer here, both are fine so I suggested both. Your bug though is that you store `count = list.Count` but then `list.Count` changes so the memoised value is incorrect. You could have used `count = list.Count * 2` as well to fix the bug while still memoising. Your efficiency flaw though is that you are copying `count * (count - 1) / 2` elements over the course of running it, which makes it much slower than it needs to be.

Comment: @Jon Hanna Yes both condition operator are different but in this case both works same. Regarding memorized list.Count, local variable count is ValueType which store copy of list.count and wont change as list change which will same though out loop. performance of code..hmmm yes we can have sorted list like first find list whose index is even then iterate with sorted list which will decrease efficiency from O(N) to O(N/2)..

Comment: "local variable count is ValueType which store copy of list.count and wont change as list change which will same though out loop" Exactly. that's your bug. That's why your code here doesn't work when the list has 3 or more elements in it.
"hmmm yes we can have sorted list like first find list whose index is even then iterate with sorted list" huh?
"decrease efficiency from O(N) to O(N/2)" O(N/2) is the same thing as O(N).

Answer (score 1):

To address the comment:

> without loop is it possible with list because my performance has gone down because of loop

While it's not possible to avoid looping entirely and staying with the same structure (but see below), we can massively improve on the multiple inserts.

Every time you do an insert, all elements later in the list have to be copied within the internal structure. So for an n-element list there will be `n-1` copy operations with a total of `n * (n - 1) / 2` elements being copied (since the number of elements copied goes down each time. This means the time taken becomes roughly O(n<sup>2</sup>)—quadratic time. Which is bad.

We can do much better by first making the list double in size, and then copying the elements to their new positons. Since we only have to do `n * 2` copies we are now doing this in O(n)—linear time.

To double the list's size we add it to itself. This is both convenient (we don't need to create another collection, or call `Add()` repeatedly) and takes advantage of the fact that `List<T>.AddRange()` has an optimisation for dealing well with lists being added to themselves:

```
list.AddRange(list);
```

Now, say the list contained `{"1", "2", "3"}`. It now contains `{"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"}` and we want `{"1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"}`.

So we start with the last element of the original set (`list[2]`) and copy it to the last two positions, then move backwards through the list. Because we're moving backwards while copying forwards we don't end up copying into a position that has yet to be copied from (if we started in the beginning we'd just be copying the same `"1"` everywhere.

```
public static void DoupleUp(List<string> list)
{
  if(list == null || list.Count == 0)
      return;
  list.AddRange(list);
  for(int idx = list.Count / 2 - 1; idx != -1; --idx)
  {
    T el = list[idx];
    list[idx * 2] = el;
    list[idx * 2 + 1] = el;
  }
}
```

Now all that's left is to realise that there's nothing specifically string-related about this, and genericise the method so we can use it on all lists:

```
public static void DoupleUp<T>(List<T> list)
{
  if(list == null || list.Count == 0)
      return;
  list.AddRange(list);
  for(int idx = list.Count / 2 - 1; idx != -1; --idx)
  {
    T el = list[idx];
    list[idx * 2] = el;
    list[idx * 2 + 1] = el;
  }
}
```

After fixing the bug in Ankush's answer, I did a test run where I started with `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList()` (the numbers 0 to 9 as strings) and then called his `Operation` on it 15 times, then went back to the original list and called my `DoubleUp` 15 times (15 isn't much, but it doubles each time so the final call is turning a list of 163840 elements into one with 327680 elements).

On my machine doing this with `Operation` takes around 12.8 seconds, while doing it with `DoubleUp` takes around 0.01 seconds.

If however you were going to iterate through this list only once, then you'd be much better creating the list on the fly:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DoubleElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
  foreach(T item in source)
  {
    yield return item;
    yield return item;
  }  
}
```

Then you could just use `foreach(string str in DoubleElements(myarray))` without even having to change from using an array.

You could even generalise this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
  foreach(T item in source)
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      yield return item;
}
```

And then use `foreach(string str in RepeatElements(myarray, 2))`.

Now, if you **really** need to avoid looping, you'll have to do something very different again, and it will take away some possible further use:

```
public class RepeatList<T> : IList<T>
{
  private readonly IList<T> _backing;
  private readonly int _repeats;
  public RepeatList(IList<T> backing, int repeats)
  {
    if(backing == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("backing");
    if(repeats < 1)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("repeats");
    _backing = backing;
    _repeats = repeats;
  }
  public RepeatList(int repeats)
    : this(new List<T>(), repeats)
  {
  }
  public T this[int index]
  {
    get { return _backing[index / _repeats]; }
    set { _backing[index / _repeats] = value; }
  }
  public int Count
  {
    get { return _backing.Count * _repeats; }
  }
  public bool IsReadOnly
  {
    get { return _backing.IsReadOnly; }
  }
  public int IndexOf(T item)
  {
    int idx = _backing.IndexOf(item);
    return idx >= 0 ? idx * _repeats : -1;
  }
  public void Insert(int index, T item)
  {
    _backing.Insert(index / _repeats, item);
  }
  public void RemoveAt(int index)
  {
    _backing.RemoveAt(index / _repeats);
  }
  public void Add(T item)
  {
    _backing.Add(item);
  }
  public void Clear()
  {
    _backing.Clear();
  }
  public bool Contains(T item)
  {
    return _backing.Contains(item);
  }
  public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
  {
    if(array == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if(arrayIndex < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arrayIndex");
    if(array.Length - arrayIndex < _backing.Count * _repeats)
      throw new ArgumentException("array is too small to copy all elements starting from index " + arrayIndex);
    foreach(T item in this)
      array[arrayIndex++] = item;
  }
  public bool Remove(T item)
  {
    return _backing.Remove(item);
  }
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    foreach(T item in _backing)
      for(int i = 0; i != _repeats; ++i)
        yield return item;
  }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

This will create such a list in constant time: `var rep = new RepeatList<string>(myArray, 2)` returns pretty much immediately.

It mutates as `myArray` does (change element 2 of `myArray` and you change elements 4 and 5 of `rep`) and if used with a non-readonly backing list this goes both ways, including calls to `Add` in fact adding 2 elements. You can minimise the strangeness by making it readonly and having all of the mutating members throw `NotSupportedException` but it can also be useful to have the write-through happen.